# lua syntax questions regarding micro optimizations

Tags: syntax, lua

So I'm trying to figure out which would be best overall for performance between syntax usages with lua.

I have 3 examples that all basically do the same thing but I'm wondering in what order they would rank in terms of performance:

ex 1.

```
local test_var = true
for i = 1,3 do
    if test_var then
        return
    end
    print('test')
end
```

ex. 2

```
local test_var = true
for i = 1,3 do
    if test_var then
        break
    end
    print('test')
end
```

ex. 3

```
local test_var = false
for i = 1,3 do
    if not test_var then
        return
    end
    print(test)
end
```

ex. 4

```
local test_var = false
for i = 1,3 do
    if not test_var then
        goto continue
    end
    print('test')
    ::continue::
end
```

ex. 5

```
local test_var = false
for i = 1,3 do
    if test_var then
        print('test')
    end
end
```

there are probably also a few other variations of how this could be written but basically I'm just looking for what would be the absolute best performance wise. while this is quite simple stuff its being used for I'm planning to reorganize every usage I have so far in alot of scripts I'm running and some do some rather complex work so I'm hoping to improve things as much as I can

Comment: `if not test_var then` has exactly the same performance as `if test_var then`

Comment: What Lua environment and version?

Comment: 5.1(I think, otherwise its 5.2) but its for the game garry's mod so it has some additional modifications(some being added opperators for continue, ! and ||. aswell it uses JIT for it too)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: I see an extra operator there. Does luac do some kind of shortcut when it sees `if not`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Just don't
2. Try benchmarking it
3. Still, **just don't**

Seriously, if you're using Lua, you shouldn't be trying to optimize on that level, specially if you don't understand the internals enough to answer those questions for yourself.

A few hints though:

- If you're using LuaJIT, don't bother. The compiler is smarter than you and will get the code to run as fast as possible if you just focus on readability and idiomatic Lua without having to do any "optimization" nonesense.
- If you're using PUC Lua, your use case probably doesn't need crazy performance anyway, otherwise you would be using LuaJIT or a system programming language.
- Focus on higher-level optimizations instead. Reducing table allocations and function closing gives you way more of a performance increase than the minor changes you're asking about.
- Be careful with assumptions about the Lua VM. It might seem "intuitive" that `goto` is faster than a loop construct, because it's a more "low level" thing, but the Lua VM has special instructions for many syntax constructs like for loops, so they may well perform *better* than plain gotos.
- Write benchmarks. It's incredibly easy to throw together a simple benchmark in Lua so you really should just be testing for yourself what code runs better in a real-life scenario. Just remember to run your benchmark on several Lua versions.
- Don't optimize the wrong code.

And lastly, just move the condition out of the loop.

---

PS: A note about asking questions

When asking about performance, always give realistic numbers or comment their ranges. When variables can change over time, comment it or add some dummy code to change them.

The way you asked your question, the naive answer would be:

```lua
if test_var then
   print("test") print("test") print("test")
end
```

and it wouldn't even be wrong.

Comment: well the thing is this is technically for a game called garry's mod which not only adds other opperators for things such as not/or aswell as continue but it also already uses LuaJIT. thing is however nobody but facepunch has access to the implementation for any of that. and most of these are already close enough to each other where its really difficult to actually get any clearn tell tale sign of one being more optimized than the other.

as for the Just Don't part, theres really no choice. Optimization is a must in all cases to me.

Comment: @RapadantNetworks you may want to look at some examples of performance testing, they are intened to show the small differences, and you decide how many digits matter to you. [Lua Gems: Lua Performance Tips](https://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf). If you are saying a test can't show you a difference then i believe you have your answer.

Comment: @RapadantNetworks You can still keep in mind what is true for every language: Every instructions takes some time at some point. So an `if not <condition>` will always take at least one instruction more than a plain `if <condition>` (it may already happen in the compiler, but it takes that 1 instruction more *somewhere*). Also, if your condition is constant and your loop body does nothing if the condition isnt met: simply avoid the loop at all by checking the condition once before entering the loop.